# Will parameters not stored in a variable be copied at runtime?

Tags: c++

I have the following code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

void foo(string input){
    //perform operations...
}

int main(){
    string x, y;
    cin >> x;
    cin >> y;
    foo(x + y);
    return 0;
}
```

Will the parameters of foo be copied at runtime? In other words, will x and y be concatenated, then copied, and then passed to foo? or will they be concatenated and passed to foo, without being copied for the pass to foo?

Is there a way to test this? I am unsure what to search so links are appreciated if a similar question already exists

Comment: 'or will they be concatenated and passed to foo, without being copied' is plain silly

Comment: @DieterLücking could you explain why this is silly? Your comment does not help further my understanding of my original question

Answer (score 2):

> will x and y be concatenated, then copied, and then passed to foo? or will they be concatenated and passed to foo, without being copied?

This depends entirely on the compiler. Both are valid behavior. With optimizations turned on it's very likely that the copy is omitted.

> Is there a way to test this?

Yes. Use your own class that prints something in its constructors.

Answer (score 1):

First, let's establish that to do the concatenation a copy of both original strings must be made into a temporary string (otherwise where would the full concatenated value go?).

Then notionally a copy is made to pass to you `foo` function. However the compiler is allowed (but not required) to *elide* this copy if it wishes. Either behavior is standards conforming and should not affect your design.

Comment: "a copy of both original strings must be made into a temporary string" – Not necessarily, f.ex. if neither `x` or `y` is used after the `foo` call.

Comment: @zenith Are you trying to say it's possible to concatenate x and y without copying x and y? I can't see how that's possible without a blatant textbook case of buffer overfow?

Comment: @tux3 If `x` or `y` isn't going to be used after the concatenation then the concatenation can be optimized to just modify that string (if it has enough capacity left). The compiler _might_ do it even if you don't explicitly specify it (it's possible to _make_ the string have enough capacity left just to make this optimization possible, although I doubt today's compilers will go that far).

Comment: @zenith The destination string's size must be the sum of the two source strings' sizes. Unless you're concatenating with the empty string, neither source can possibly be big enough to also be the destination. Am I missing the obvious? EDIT: So, you're talking about the corner case where a string has enough extra capacity? I don't think any compiler ever implements this optimization, but I could be wrong.